# suma de descuentos

Tags: java

Me podrian ayudar con este problema por favor.

Una tienda ha puesto en oferta la venta un producto ofreciendo un descuento denominado 10%+10% que consiste en aplicar dos descuentos del 10%. El importe compra se calcula multiplicando el precio del producto por la cantidad de unidades adquiridas. El primer descuento es igual al 10% del importe compra. El segundo descuento es igual al 10% del importe que queda de restar el importe compra menos el importe del primer descuento. El importe del descuento total se calcula sumando el primer y el segundo descuento. El importe a pagar se calcula restando el importe compra menos el importe del descuento total.

Dado el precio del producto y la cantidad de unidades adquiridas, diseñe un algoritmo que determine el importe de la compra, el importe del descuento total y el importe a pagar.

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor lee [ask], y para aprender como funciona el sitio [tour]. Aca no se hace la tarea, si quieres que alguien te ayude debes motrar un minimo de esfuerzo para resolverlo con un [example], y tener un problema especifico y claro.

Answer (score 0):

```
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
            //VARIABLES
            
            int cantUnidades;
            double impCompra,impAPagar,precioProducto,dsctoTotal,dscto1,dscto2;
            
            //DATOS DE ENTRADA
            
            cantUnidades = Integer.parseInt(txtcantUnidades.getText());
            precioProducto = Double.parseDouble(txtprecioProducto.getText());
            
            //CALCULO
            
            impCompra = precioProducto*cantUnidades;
            dscto1 = impCompra *0.10;   
            dscto2 = (impCompra-dscto1)*0.10;
            dsctoTotal = dscto1+ dscto2;
            impAPagar = impCompra-dsctoTotal;
            
            //SALIDA
            
            txtS.setText("DATOS INGRESADOS"+"\n");
            txtS.append("El importe a la compra es: "+impCompra+"\n");
            txtS.append("El primer descuento del 10% es: "+dscto1+"\n");
            txtS.append("El segundo descuento del 10% es: "+dscto2+"\n");
            txtS.append("El descuento total es: "+dsctoTotal+"\n");
            txtS.append("El importe a pagar es: : "+impAPagar); 
        }
```

Comment: Me llego a salir, por si alguno se sirve.